# Python os and gttts mp3 file error

Tags: python, macos, operating-system

I'm trying to make a program that needs a `.mp3` file printing. I used **gTTS** and **os** modules to do.

In the code, I usually use the **os** module, but when I run the code, I cannot hear the sound even if I make it louder.

**Here is my code:**

```
def open_file(filename):
if sys.platform == "win32":
    os.startfile(filename)
else:
    opener ="open" if sys.platform == "darwin" else "xdg-open"
    subprocess.call([opener, filename])
open_file(Warning.mp3)
messagebox.showinfo("현재 시간", printText)
```

**Note:** 현재시간 is in Korean. Sorry for that.

I think I get the error because I wrote `'win32'`, but I'm on maOS X (macOS x: **El Capitan**). I know what is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help me debug this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You say you are converting mp3 files to text so I think you should try out this module https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/ 
and convert mp3 for converting mp3 files to text.Hope it helps. But if you are trying text to mp3 then you can also try `pyttsx` which uses default speech library on most is.